# textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText: returning NO, but autocorrect ignores?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

I'm having the following problem, and am not sure if this is an iOS bug, or I'm misunderstanding UITextViewDelegate callbacks. I'm able to reproduce this behavior on my device (iPad retina) and on the simulator *only if* I use the software keyboard (i.e. use my mouse to click the on-screen keyboard).

Consider the following contrived example project **(Updated 1/9/14)**:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1q3vqfnsmmbhnuj/AutocorrectBug.zip

It's a simple UITextView, with a view controller set as its delegate, with the following delegate method:

```
- (BOOL) textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {

    if ([text isEqualToString:@" "]
        && range.length == 0
        && (range.location == 0
            || [[textView.text substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(range.location-1, 1)] isEqualToString:@"\n"])) {
                textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
                return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

My intention with this code is that when the user types a space **(edit: and that space is the first character on the line)**, the space is ignored and instead some other functionality happens, in this case the UITextView turns yellow.

Now consider these steps:

1. Tap in the text view to make it first responder
2. Type "Apple", hit return and note the positioning
3. Now, type a space (turning the text view yellow), type "Apple" again and hit return.

Expected: A yellow background and text reading:

```
Apple
Apple
```

Observed: A yellow background and text reading (due to an autocorrection):

```
Apple
 Apple
```

It appears the autocorrection logic is ignoring the result of textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:.

- **Is this expected behavior?**
- **If so can it be worked around?**

**Edit 1/9/14: only the first space on a line should be ignored, further spaces should be processed as normal (i.e. inserted into the text), ruling out a brute force strip of spaces. Also I'm dealing with a large string (potentially hundreds of thousands of characters) in a text editor (meaning constant user typing), so analyzing the entire string with every keystroke isn't going to be performant.**

Comment: Will you consider disabling the autocorrect for that UITextField. Setting the autocorrectionType for it.

Comment: @RaymondBrion I'd like to avoid that solution if possible, autocorrection is otherwise desirable here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I see it too on my iPad 7.0.3 simulator.

One way to solve it is to add this `UITextViewDelegate` method:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    // eliminates spaces, including those introduced by autocorrect
    if ([textView.text rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]].location != NSNotFound) {
        textView.text = [textView.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    }
}
```

---

#### Update

It seems that this delegate method *is* called after autocorrection, just that the in the case you want to prevent (where "Apple" becomes " Apple") the replacement text is " Apple" and not " ". So to modify the implementation to prevent "\n " but allow other " " characters in your text, you could try comparing the first character of `text` to " " instead of comparing `text` to " ".

```
- (BOOL) textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
    
    // compare first character to 'space' character by decimal value
    if (text.length && [text characterAtIndex:0] == 32) {
        
        // check if previous character is a newline
        NSInteger locationOfPreviousCharacter = range.location - 1;
        if (locationOfPreviousCharacter < 0 || [textView.text characterAtIndex:locationOfPreviousCharacter] == 10) {
            textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
            return NO;
        }
    }
    
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: +1 for a perfectly valid solution; however it shows me I mis-phrased my question. Only the first space on a line should be ignored as I describe, further spaces on the same line should be treated as normal. Also, I'm dealing with very large strings (up to hundreds of thousands of characters), so analyzing the entire string for each typed letter isn't going to be performant.

Comment: This would work. Will replace only the first occurence of the string

NSRange location = [text rangeOfString:@" "];

NSString* result = [someString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:location withString:text];

textView.text = result;

Comment: I see... do you also mean that spaces should be removed only if they are the first **character** on a line? So that if the first space is not the first character in its line, it should also be ignored?